# How to accomplish corecursion in C++?

Tags: c++, corecursion

I'm working on a C++ project that requires frequent interaction with a tree structure, which means lots of recursive functions, and I'm looking for ways to improve the code. I came across [corecursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corecursion) the other day, and I'm interested in exploring this strategy for my application.

However, I haven't been able to find any examples of how to accomplish corecursion with C++. To make my question specific, how can I do [this tree traversal using corecursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corecursion#Tree_traversal) in C++?

```
def bf(tree):
    tree_list = [tree]
    while tree_list:
        new_tree_list = []
        for tree in tree_list:
            if tree is not None:
                yield tree.value
                new_tree_list.append(tree.left)
                new_tree_list.append(tree.right)
        tree_list = new_tree_list
```

If doing this is just a bad idea, let me know. That said, having *some* answer to this on the internet would be useful for those trying to do this in the future. There are no questions on SO matching `[c++] corecursion` and the rest of the internet seems devoid of useful information on the subject.

Comment: @forcebru yes you are missing something.  corecursion is easy to express in pythonm so the OP used python to express it.  The OP wants to do corecursion in C++, not python, but does not know how.

Comment: @Yakk, then he should mark it Python as well, at least.

Comment: The old-school sneaky C stuff might make some frown, but there's a cool implementation [here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html) :)

Comment: @ForceBru: No, I do not believe so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is almost identical to the given python implementation and you can use it now in production:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c080b19cf4ebf4ce)</kbd>**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/coroutine/all.hpp>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    char value;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};

using generator =
    boost::coroutines::asymmetric_coroutine<decltype(Node::value)>::pull_type;

generator bf(Node *tree) {                                //def bf(tree):
    return generator([=](auto &yield) {                   //
        vector<Node *> tree_list = {tree};                //    tree_list = [tree]
        while (!tree_list.empty()) {                      //    while tree_list:
            vector<Node *> new_tree_list;                 //        new_tree_list = []
            for (auto tree : tree_list) {                 //        for tree in tree_list:
                if (tree != nullptr) {                    //            if tree is not None:
                    yield(tree->value);                   //                yield tree.value
                    new_tree_list.push_back(tree->left);  //                new_tree_list.append(tree.left)
                    new_tree_list.push_back(tree->right); //                new_tree_list.append(tree.right)
                }                                         //
            }                                             //
            tree_list = move(new_tree_list);              //        tree_list = new_tree_list
        }                                                 //
    });                                                   //
}                                                         //

int main() {
    Node a{'a'}, b{'b'}, c{'c'}, d{'d'}, e{'e'};

    a.left = &b;
    a.right = &c;
    b.right = &d;
    d.left = &e;

    for (auto node_value : bf(&a))
        std::cout << node_value << " ";
}
```

To avoid allocations/deallocations I'd probably do it this way:

```
generator bf(Node *tree) {
    return generator([=](auto &yield) {
        vector<Node *> tree_list = {tree}, new_tree_list;
        while (!tree_list.empty()) {
            for (auto tree : tree_list) {
                if (tree != nullptr) {
                    yield(tree->value);
                    new_tree_list.push_back(tree->left);
                    new_tree_list.push_back(tree->right);
                }
            }
            swap(tree_list, new_tree_list);
            new_tree_list.clear();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

So there are a few approaches.

You can wait for the await keyword to arrive, as proposed, but that seems long term.  If you do wait for await, [here is someone implementing yield with await](http://luiscubal.blogspot.ca/2013/10/introducing-nwarpasync-emulating-yield.html), which at least at first glance should work in C++.

You can write a generating iterator helper, or borrow one from boost, and make a generator from it.

You can use a mutable lambda stored in a `std::function`, maybe returning a `std::experimental::optional` (or boost optional).

But those mostly just make it pretty.  So lets get ugly.  I will write this in C++14, because lazy.

```
struct generator {
  using trees=std::vector<tree>;
  trees m_cur;      
  trees m_next;
  bool next(value* v){
    while(true){
      if (m_cur.empty()){
        m_cur=std::move(m_next);
        m_next.clear();
        std::reverse(begin(m_cur),end(m_cur));
        if(m_cur.empty())
          return false;
      }
      auto t = m_cur.back();
      m_cur.pop_back();
      if(!t)continue;
      *v = get_value(t);
      m_next.push_back(get_left(t));
      m_next.push_back(get_right(t));
      return true;
    }
  }
  generator(tree t):m_cur{t}{};
};
```

The tree type needs free functiins to get value, get left and right, and an operator! to tell if it is null.  And it needs to be copyable (a pointer would do).

Use:

```
generator g(some_tree);
value v;
while(g.next(&v)){
  std::cout<<v<<'\n';
}
```

Now this is ugly -- we maintain the state manually for example.

A more magic way is coming via await I believe, but that is not standardized.

A generator iterator would hide the ugly interface behind an iterator fascade, but state is still managed manually.

You might be able to do something fancy with lambdas, but I am unsure if a lambda can return its own type.  Maybe.  (G:{}->{G,Maybe X} or somesuch)

---

Now, because it is awesome, here is the [n4134](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4134.pdf) proposed `await`/`yield` solution.

```
template<class T0, class...Ts>
std::vector<std::decay_t<T0>> vec_of(T0&& t0, Ts&&... ts) {
  return {std::forward<T0>(t0), std::forward<Ts>(ts)...};
}
auto breadth_first = [](auto&& tree){
  auto tree_list = vec_of(decltype(tree)(tree));
  while(!tree_list.empty()) {
    decltype(tree_list) new_tree_list;
    for(auto&& tree:tree_list) {
      if (tree) {
        yield get_value(tree);
        new_tree_list.push_back(get_left(tree));
        new_tree_list.push_back(get_right(tree));
      }
    }
    tree_list = std::move(new_tree_list);
  }
};
```

which is basically a line to line translation of the python code.  I did write a `vec_of` helper function to replace `[]` in python.

Use:

```
for(auto&& value : breadth_first(tree)) {
  std::cout << value;
}
```

which is pretty.

Comment: I also like awaiting `await`... and yes, a lambda can capture itself as a means for recursion, and the same concept appears to apply to returning itself, albeit with a wrinkle or two - you have to use nested lambdas, and potentially (?) dynamic allocation. Here's the page I was looking at: http://cpptruths.blogspot.com/2013/10/creating-recursive-lambdas-and.html. Seems like more effort than it's worth, but mostly because other languages handle it so elegantly.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.  The problem is more about the nature of `yield` though  co-iterators.

Basically, if you need to `yield` in C++, you need to implement an iterator-like state machine, which is pretty much the idea of co-recursion anyhow.

A working example would require implementing a tree class, but here is a partial implementation of BFS using what is basically the strategy in the wiki article (fixed a little because their algorithm is a bit silly)

```
for (bfs_generator i = bfs_generator(myTree);
    i.is_good();
    i.next())
{
  print (i.value());
}

// Iterator-style operation overloads may be more appropriate, but I don't want to deal with the syntactic details
// I assume a standard C Node struct with left and right pointers implementation of your tree.
class bfs_iterator
{
  // The Python example is a little strange because it expresses the state as two lists, when only one is necessary
  std::queue<Node *> tree_list;

  public:
  bfs_iterator (Node * root)
  {
    tree_list.push_back(root);
  }

  bool is_good()
  {
    return tree_list.empty();
  }

  void next()
  {
    // Pop the front of the queue then add the children to the queue.
    if (!tree_list.empty())
    {
      Node * node = tree_list.front();
      tree_list.pop();

      if (node->left)
        tree_list.push(node->left);
      if (node->right)
        tree_list.push(node->right);
    }
  }

  MyTree::value value()
  {
    return tree_list.front()->value;
  }
};
```

Technically, you don't need to mimic their `yield` generator strategy to do this.  Rather than defining the class, you could simple use the queue directly in your code.

This differs a bit from the wikipedia algorithm because... well the wiki algorithm isn't ideal.  They're mostly identical, but the wikipedia example is kind of a poor-man's queue.

Comment: Could this be done with a pair of implementation wrappers? E.g. `impl1<X> &&` and `impl2<X> &&` store data `X` as well as one `std::result_of<X::work>` or even different types. Each conversion moves `X` from one to the other and does one atom of work along the way. The mutually-referential relationship shouldn't be a problem for CRTP unless there's something I'm missing.